# I got this error while uploading django project to pythonware

Tags: django

25/03/2020 https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/rohanhirwe32/files/var/log/rohanhirwe32.pythonanywhere.com.error.log
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/rohanhirwe32/files/var/log/rohanhirwe32.pythonanywhere.com.error.log 1/1
2020-03-25 08:19:48,249: Error running WSGI application
2020-03-25 08:19:48,263: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
2020-03-25 08:19:48,263: File "/var/www/rohanhirwe32_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 15, in

2020-03-25 08:19:48,264: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-03-25 08:19:48,264:
2020-03-25 08:19:48,264: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12,
in get_wsgi_application
2020-03-25 08:19:48,264: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-03-25 08:19:48,264:
2020-03-25 08:19:48,265: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in
setup
2020-03-25 08:19:48,265: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2020-03-25 08:19:48,265:
2020-03-25 08:19:48,265: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
91, in populate
2020-03-25 08:19:48,265: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2020-03-25 08:19:48,265:
2020-03-25 08:19:48,266: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90,
in create
2020-03-25 08:19:48,266: module = import_module(entry)
2020-03-25 08:19:48,266: ***************************************************
2020-03-25 08:19:48,266: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-03-25 08:19:48,267: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug:
2020-03-25 08:19:48,267: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-03-25 08:19:48,267: ***************************************************
2020-03-25 08:19:50,917: Error running WSGI application
2020-03-25 08:19:50,917: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
2020-03-25 08:19:50,918: File "/var/www/rohanhirwe32_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 15, in

2020-03-25 08:19:50,918: application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-03-25 08:19:50,918:
2020-03-25 08:19:50,918: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12,
in get_wsgi_application
2020-03-25 08:19:50,918: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919:
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in
setup
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919:
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
91, in populate
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2020-03-25 08:19:50,919:
2020-03-25 08:19:50,920: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90,
in create
2020-03-25 08:19:50,920: module = import_module(entry)
2020-03-25 08:19:50,920: ***************************************************
2020-03-25 08:19:50,920: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2020-03-25 08:19:50,920: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug:
2020-03-25 08:19:50,921: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2020-03-25 08:19:50,921: ***************************************************

Comment: Try this  pip install django-bootstrap4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the really badly formatted trace log, your problem is could be found in this line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
```

Install package with your local virtual environment:

```
pip install bootstrap4
```

and do export modules list to requirements:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Update your repo and deploy it to Pythonanywhere.